# What is this website architecture called?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, webforms, soa

Our main application interface is a website written in ASP.NET Webforms.
For the most part, all html/content is generated server side, with some javascript/AJAX sprinkled in where necessary.

Management has decided to move new development in a different direction. No content will be generated server side. Instead, we will only expose WCF web services which return very simple JSON objects that contain UI data munged together from business objects.

All of our actual pages will contain a small amount of html, and scripts which will pull the data from the services asynchronously to populate JQuery UI elements.

I don't really have an issue with this, and I can see where it nicely decouples the presentation layer from the data. But I'm not sure exactly what to call this? We've clearly split off the View from everything else, but I don't think the above strictly qualifies as MVC, depending on how the backend is implemented. Would it be called a service oriented architecture? I've heard that term thrown around a few times.

Are there any major downfalls to doing things this way?

Comment: So your management is forgoing any search engines, eh?

Comment: @WyattBarnett The Site is just an application interface, it is not public.

Comment: Oh, well, then carry on . . ..

Answer (score 1):

It's called Service Oriented Architecture (SOA). Your data is pulled from a service (ie middle tier which is completely separated from the presentation layer. What's great about this architecture is that you can have various front end's (ie clients) plug in to the service without having to rebuild the whole thing entirely. So it makes it easier to build Iphone, Android, Web, Desktop, and Windows Phone versions of your software.

Comment: Nor did my answer intend it to be. I was simply confirming that the overall architecture would be considered SOA. Whether the use web forms and J SON objects together or strictly web forms themselves is up to them. I was part of a project that was very similar that tried to cram developers into a particular technology and saw it fail miserably. The intention and concept is noble but trying to force a solution because it may seem "ideal" can have some nasty repercussions, especially if management and not the architect is making the decision.

Comment: This is not SOA. The question did not mention service reuse, agnostic services, service inventories, service compositions or use of enterprise service bus. Simply using services does not constitute SOA. Please stop adding to all the confusion surrounding SOA.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is "it depends what architecture patterns you apply", because you could build any number of them that way.

In the context I would guess that "MVC" is the right way to do it; consider: if you wrote the model in your server-side language and rendered HTML there, but the data was passed inside the application as JSON, would it be MVC?